# Eclipse restart using 'PlatformUI.getWorkbench().restart()' is not restarting the RCP product

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

Upon invoking the method `PlatformUI.getWorkbench().restart()` the application is simply closing and refusing to restart the product.

Comment: Have you written your own `IApplication`?

Comment: no, i just invoked restart()

Comment: @greg-449:  Anything specific i need to implement apart from invoking restart() method ?

Comment: Are you testing the restart behavior outside of Eclipse? The reason I am asking is: if you launch your RCP application from within Eclipse, then the eclipse.exe is able to detect this restart and then launches your application again. When you are starting the VM by yourself then you need some similar behaviour - I guess this is what @greg-449 has in mind regarding the `IApplication`.

Comment: yes, I'm restarting the RCP product outside eclipse (i.e.., I'd exported the product and I'm trying to restart the product.exe).

Comment: If you are using an RCP with your own `IApplication` then you need to do stuff in the application. If you are using an existing application it will hopefully already be doing this.

Comment: Yes @greg-449, I'm using my own IApplication . what stuff i need to do in order to perform restart of my application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `IApplication` needs to check the return code from `PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench` in the `start` method:

The simplest is:

```
int returnCode = PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(display, advisor);
if (returnCode == PlatformUI.RETURN_RESTART)
   return IApplication.EXIT_RESTART;

return IApplication.EXIT_OK;
```

More recent applications seem to use this:

```
private static final String SYSTEM_PROPERTY_EXIT_CODE = "eclipse.exitcode";

int returnCode = PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(display, advisor);

if (returnCode == PlatformUI.RETURN_RESTART)
 {
   // eclipse.exitcode system property may be set to re-launch
   if (IApplication.EXIT_RELAUNCH.equals(Integer.getInteger(SYSTEM_PROPERTY_EXIT_CODE)))
      return IApplication.EXIT_RELAUNCH;

   return IApplication.EXIT_RESTART;
 }

return IApplication.EXIT_OK;
```

Comment: Hi @greg-449, Even after modifying the start method (of the class derived from IApplication instance), I'm not able to restart my product. I also tried launching the product in Remote debugging mode, and found that the break-point was not hitting at this method while exiting.

Comment: Am i missing anything ?

Comment: Are you sure it the `IApplication` is being used at all?

Comment: I've posted my usage of the start method.

Comment: That looks fine. Have you checked the .log file in the workspace .metadata for any crashes? Possibly also any xxx.log in the installation 'configuration' directory.

Comment: I checked the .log file, and the message posted above is its contents (.log file contents).

Comment: That looks more like a startup error, check the date/time in the log matches the shutdown

Comment: Sorry but you are going to have to do some detailed debugging to find out what is going on

Comment: Hi Greg, Thank you so much for your support. I'd fixed this issue.