# RCP application is not restarted

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, java-web-start, rcp

I have my own `IApplication` and modify `start()` as:

```
@Override
    public Object start( IApplicationContext context )
    {
        LOGGER.debug( "Application.start(IApplicationContext context " + context + ")" );

        Display display = PlatformUI.createDisplay();
        try
        {
            int returnCode = PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench( display, new ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor() );
            if (returnCode == PlatformUI.RETURN_RESTART)
            {
                return IApplication.EXIT_RESTART;
            }

            return IApplication.EXIT_OK;
        }
        finally
        {
            display.dispose();
        }
    }
```

and i call `PlatformUI.getWorkbench().restart();`in one of my handler for one of my button.
It works fine when i run within Eclipse, but the app is just shutdown when I build as a java webstart.

I read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24890851/eclipse-restart-using-platformui-getworkbench-restart-is-not-restarting-th) and as my understanding is that it won't work if it isn't launched by eclipse.exe. However, I haven't found what is the final solution for it. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

From the Eclipse [help](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fjava_web_start.htm) on using Java Web Start:

> **Known limitations**
>
> Request to exit the application with a restart code are ignored;

So this isn't currently possible.